# Permutações de um número inteiro desconsiderando os zeros à esquerda

Tags: java, matemática

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Dada uma entrada `n` tenho que calcular o número de permutações possíveis com os dígitos que o compõem. Por exemplo, se `n = 123` tenho 6 números que podem ser formados: `123`, `132`, `231`, `213`, `312`, `321`. Porém se a entrada for `100` a resposta seria 1, já que as permutações possíveis são: `001`, `010` e `001` mas `001`, `010` não são representações válidas para o problema.

Aplicando a fórmula matemática para permutação com repetição, cheguei no seguinte código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Similaridade {

  public int solucao(int n) {
    List<Integer> digitos = separarDigitos(n);
    Map<Integer, Integer> ocorrencias;
    Integer resultado;
    Integer[] valores;

    ocorrencias = this.contarOcorrencias(digitos);
    valores = ocorrencias.values().toArray(new Integer[ocorrencias.size()]);
    resultado = this.calcularPermutacao(digitos.size(), valores);

    return resultado;
  }

  public Integer calcularPermutacao(Integer total, Integer... repeticoes) {
    Long denominador = 1L;
    Long numerador;
    Long resultado;

    for (Integer repeticao : repeticoes) {
      if (repeticao > 1) {
        denominador = denominador * this.fatorial(repeticao);
      }
    }

    numerador = this.fatorial(total);
    resultado = numerador / denominador;

    return resultado.intValue();
  }

  private List<Integer> separarDigitos(int numero) {
    List<Integer> resultado = new ArrayList<>();

    while (numero != 0) {
      int digito = numero % 10;
      numero = numero / 10;
      resultado.add(digito);
    }

    return resultado;
  }

  private Map<Integer, Integer> contarOcorrencias(List<Integer> numeros) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> ocorrencias = new HashMap<>();

    numeros.forEach((numero) -> {
      if (ocorrencias.containsKey(numero)) {
        ocorrencias.put(numero, ocorrencias.get(numero) + 1);
      } else {
        ocorrencias.put(numero, 1);
      }
    });

    return ocorrencias;
  }

  private Long fatorial(Integer numero) {
    Long resultado = 1L;

    for (int fator = 2; fator <= numero; fator++) {
      resultado = resultado * fator;
    }

    return resultado;
  }
}
```

Porém agora preciso calcular e aplicar os resultados com zeros.

Como posso fazer isso? Lembrando que a performance é importante e que, sendo assim, apenas realizar as trocas para ter todas as possibilidades não é interessante. A resolução fica mais completa aplicando o desconto na fórmula ou após o cálculo da mesma.

---

Exemplos:

- Entrada: `1213`. Saída: `12`.
- Entrada: `123`. Saída: `6`.
- Entrada: `100`. Saída: `1`.
- Entrada: `120`. Saída: `4`.
- Entrada: `1200`. Saída: `6`.
- Entrada: `0`. Saída: `1`.

Comment: Existe tempo limite para execução do programa ? Se sim quanto ? Existem restrições para o `n` ? Se sim quais?

Comment: @Isac limite não existe, mas fazendo uma a uma cada possibilidade eu já tenho pronto. O interessante seria resolver descobrindo apenas as combinações iniciando com `0` matematicamente para descontar do resultado do código atual.

Comment: Ou seja a sua ideia é por meio de alguma dedução matemática conseguir chegar à quantidade de números únicos descontabilizando números com zeros à esquerda, sem ter que iterar sobre cada um ?

Comment: @Isac sim, exatamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As fórmulas abaixo foram retiradas [daqui](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2799149).

---

Dado um número qualquer, e considerando:

- *a<sub>i</sub>* é a quantidade de vezes que o dígito `i` ocorre neste número (portanto, 0 <= `i` <= 9)

  - Ex: no número 644, o valor de *a<sub>4</sub>* é igual a 2 (existem 2 dígitos 4 no número) e *a<sub>6</sub>* é igual a 1 (todos os outros *a<sub>i</sub>* - para `i` diferente de 4 e 6 - são iguais a zero)
- `n` é a quantidade de dígitos do número, ou seja, é a soma de todos os *a<sub>i</sub>*:
  *a<sub>0</sub>* + *a<sub>1</sub>* + ... + *a<sub>9</sub>* = `n`

O total de permutações possíveis (incluindo as que tem zeros no início) é:

```
n! / (a₀! * a₁! * a₂! * ... * a₉!)
```

Se o número não tem nenhum zero (ou seja, *a<sub>0</sub>* é igual a zero), então o valor acima já é a resposta.

Mas se há algum zero no número, então podemos colocar um deles no início, restando *a<sub>0</sub> - 1* zeros no restante do número (ou seja, basta rearranjar os dígitos restantes para saber a quantidade). Sendo assim, a quantidade de permutações que possuem um zero no início seria:

```
(n - 1)! / ((a₀ - 1)! * a₁! * a₂! * ... * a₉!)
```

Portanto, caso haja zeros, basta fazer a primeira fórmula acima menos a segunda, que teremos o resultado. Se não tiver nenhum zero, a primeira fórmula já é a resposta. Em Java ficaria assim:

```java
public int solucao(int n) {
    int[] quantidades = new int[10];
    int nDigits = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        nDigits++;
        quantidades[n % 10]++;
        n /= 10;
    }

    // multiplica os fatoriais de a1 até a9
    int d = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < quantidades.length; i++) {
        d *= fatorial(quantidades[i]);
    }

    // total de permutações
    int totalPerms = fatorial(nDigits) / (d * fatorial(quantidades[0]));
    if (quantidades[0] == 0) { // não tem zeros
        return totalPerms;
    }
    // descontar as permutações que começam com zero
    return totalPerms - (fatorial(nDigits - 1) / (d * fatorial(quantidades[0] - 1)));
}
```

Como estou computando a quantidade dos dígitos de zero a 9, guardei esses valores em um array de `int` mesmo, com 10 posições (o elemento da posição zero é a quantidade de zeros, na posição 1 é a quantidade de `1`, etc). Além de ficar mais simples, também evita o uso dos *wrappers*.

O método `fatorial` é o mesmo que você já tem (apesar de que seria possível melhorar isso com [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33438/112052), fica a sugestão). E também poderia mudar todos os `int`'s para `long`'s, caso vá trabalhar com números muito grandes, nos quais o fatorial estoura os limites de um `int`.

---

Outra alternativa é considerar, além das definições acima:

- `bn(n, k)`: fórmula do [Binômio de Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), ou seja, `bn(n, k)` é igual a `n! / k! (n - k)!` (sendo que `n!` é o fatorial de `n`)

Temos que o total de permutações possíveis, desconsiderando os zeros no início, é:

```
bn(n - 1, a₀) * bn(n - a₀, a₁) * bn(n - a₀ - a₁, a₂) * ... * bn(a₉, a₉)
```

A ideia é similar: se colocar um zero no início, todos os outros dígitos (independente de ser zero ou não) podem ser colocados depois. A fórmula acima faz este "desconto", e também pode ser generalizada para:

```
bn(n - 1, a₀) * ( (n - a₀)! / (a₁! * a₂! * ... * a₉!) )
```

Em Java ficaria:

```java
public int solucao(int n) {
    int[] quantidades = new int[10];
    int nDigits = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        nDigits++;
        quantidades[n % 10]++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    int d = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < quantidades.length; i++) {
        d *= this.fatorial(quantidades[i]);
    }
    return bn(nDigits - 1, quantidades[0]) * (this.fatorial(nDigits - quantidades[0]) / d);
}

private int bn(int n, int k) {
    return this.fatorial(n) / (this.fatorial(k) * this.fatorial(n - k));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui chegar a um resultado calculado a proporção em que o número zero aparece e descontando do cálculo de permutações. O resultado final foi o seguinte:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Similaridade {

  public int solucao(int n) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> ocorrencias = new HashMap<>();
    Integer total = this.separarDigitos(n, ocorrencias);
    Integer resultado;
    Integer[] valores;

    valores = ocorrencias.values().toArray(new Integer[ocorrencias.size()]);
    resultado = this.calcularPermutacao(total, valores);

    // Desconsidera os zeros no início
    if (ocorrencias.containsKey(0)) {
      Double quantidadeDeZeros = Double.valueOf(ocorrencias.get(0));
      Double quantidadeDeDigitos = Double.valueOf(total);
      Double provisorio = Double.valueOf(resultado);

      provisorio = provisorio - (provisorio / (quantidadeDeDigitos / quantidadeDeZeros));
      resultado = provisorio.intValue();
    }

    return resultado;
  }

  public Integer calcularPermutacao(Integer total, Integer... combinacoes) {
    Long denominador = 1L;
    Long numerador;
    Long resultado;

    for (Integer combinacao : combinacoes) {
      if (combinacao > 1) {
        denominador = denominador * this.fatorial(combinacao);
      }
    }

    numerador = this.fatorial(total);
    resultado = numerador / denominador;

    return resultado.intValue();
  }

  private Integer separarDigitos(int numero, Map<Integer, Integer> ocorrencias) {
    Integer total = 0;

    while (numero != 0) {
      int digito = numero % 10;

      numero = numero / 10;

      if (ocorrencias.containsKey(digito)) {
        ocorrencias.put(digito, ocorrencias.get(digito) + 1);
      } else {
        ocorrencias.put(digito, 1);
      }

      total++;
    }

    return total;
  }

  private Long fatorial(Integer numero) {
    Long resultado = 1L;

    for (int fator = 2; fator <= numero; fator++) {
      resultado = resultado * fator;
    }

    return resultado;
  }
}
```