# Como encontrar "Números Felizes" dentro de um intervalo?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, matemática

Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde preciso encontrar *Números Felizes* dentro de um determinado intervalo, no caso de 0 a 50, e achei isso na [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_feliz):

> Os **números felizes** são definidos pelo seguinte procedimento.
>   Começando com qualquer número inteiro positivo, o número é substituído
>   pela soma dos quadrados dos seus dígitos, e repetir o processo até que
>   o número seja igual a 1 ou até que ele entre num ciclo infinito que
>   não inclui um ou seja a soma dos quadrados dos algarismos do quadrado
>   de um número positivo inicial. Os números no fim do processo de
>   extremidade com 1, são conhecidos como **números feliz**, mas aqueles que
>   não terminam com um 1 são números chamados **infelizes**.

E consta um exemplo de como saber se o número é Feliz:

7 é um número feliz:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Se *n* não é feliz, a soma dos quadrados nunca dará 1, serão gerados
>   infinitos termos.

Como seria um algoritmo para encontrar esses números no do intervalo citado? Tenho muita dificuldade em trabalhar com potências em JavaScript.

Os números felizes entre 0 e 50 seriam:

```
1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31, 32, 44, 49
```

Eu precisava de um código para chegar a esse resultado.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Uma outra forma de fazer, é quebrando a *string* e utilizando `Math.pow` em cada um dos "pedaços", por exemplo:

```js
function beHappy(value) {

  let repeat = [];

  /**
   * Verifica se o valor é maior que 1 e se
   * o valor não é repetido, isso irá evitar
   * um loop infinito
   */
  while (value > 1 && !~repeat.indexOf(value)) {
    let result = 0;

    /**
     * Adiciona o valor para na variável
     * repeat para evitar o loop infinito
     */
    repeat.push(value);

    /* Quebra a string em pedaços */
    for (let n of value.toString().split("")) {

      /**
       * Utiliza o Math.pow para calcular a base
       * elevado ao expoente. É o mesmo que n * n
       */
      result += Math.pow(n, 2)
    }

    value = result;
  }

  return value == 1;
}

for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
  if (beHappy(i)) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Valeu! Ficou muito bom.

Comment: Só fiz uma adaptação: `var nums = []; if (beHappy(i)) nums.push(i);` para criar um array com os resultados

Comment: Pode explicar o uso de `&& !~repeat.indexOf(value)`?

Comment: @lazyFox O `~` é um [operador bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_NOT)). Se o valor de retorno do `indexOf` for `-1`, então `~-1` será igual a 0, porque `-1`é uma seqüência de caracteres de todos os 1 bits. Um pouco difícil de entender? A formula dele é `-(x + 1)`, ou `-(-1+1) = 0; -(-2+1) = 1; -(3+1) = -4`. A exclamação é para transformar o valor falso em verdadeiro, semelhante o `¬` da tabela verdade.

Comment: Muito obrigado @ValdeirPsr

Answer (score 15):

Adaptado do Rosetta Code para o SOpt:

> https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Happy_numbers#JavaScript

Licença da reprodução do documento:

> https://www.gnu.org/licenses/fdl-1.2.html

Mudei a faixa para 0-50 e pus os devidos comentários no código.

Basicamente é feito o que foi pedido no enunciado, o único detalhe
a mais que importa é o critério para sabermos a hora de parar:

Como a sequência pode ser muito grande, as únicas alternativas
que temos é achar o 1, concluindo pela "felicidade" do número,
ou achar um resultado repetido, o que caracterizaria um loop "infeliz".

```js
function happy(number) {
    var m, digit ;

    // cycle é onde vamos acumular os resultados de cada passo
    var cycle = [] ;
 
    // enquanto não encontramos o 1, nem uma repetição, vamos insistindo
    while(number != 1 && cycle[number] !== true) {
        // armazenamos o número analisado no array, para detectar repetição
        cycle[number] = true ;
        m = 0 ;
        while (number > 0) { 

            // o % extrai os dígitos 1 a 1
            digit = number % 10 ;

            // e o valor do quadrado é acumulado em m
            m += digit * digit ;
            number = (number  - digit) / 10 ;
        }
        number = m ;
    }
    return (number == 1) ;
}
 
var number = 0 ;
while(number < 50) { 
    if (happy(number)) document.write(number + " ");
    number++;
}
```

Otimização possível: armazenar os resultados anteriores marcando-os com "feliz" ou "infeliz", pois se no loop de busca surgir algum "feliz", o número de origem é "feliz" também (o oposto também é verdadeiro, se for encontrado algum "infeliz" na busca, o número de origem também é "infeliz")

Leitura recomendada, da *Enciclopédia Online de Sequências de Inteiros*:

> http://oeis.org/A007770

Comment: Boto fé. Ficou legal. Obg!

Answer (score 13):

Como a função para saber se um número é ou não feliz é uma [função pura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255557/64969), podemos usar nela [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33438/64969).

Uma maneira muito fácil de fazer memoização é com recursão. Note que a própria definição de feliz pode ser interpretada de maneira recursiva:

> Se o número em questão for 1, ele é feliz.
>
> Se o número não for 1, então ele é feliz se a soma do quadrado dos seus dígitos for feliz.

No caso, se a recursão não convergir, então isso implica que o número é infeliz (coitadinho =/ ).

Agora, será que, diferentemente da [conjectura de Collatz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276746/64969), eu consigo demonstrar que a sequência do somatório dos dígitos de um número converge para laços finitos? Sim, conseguimos. (A ideia de identificar os laços eu pesquei da [resposta do @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282776/64969))

Pegue um número grande. Nós sabemos que ele tem `n` dígitos. Qualquer número com `n` dígitos tem como soma máxima do quadrado dos seus dígitos como `n*9^2`. Basta então verificar que essa soma vai ser menor do que qualquer número de `n` dígitos. O menor número de `n` dígitos é `10^(n-1)`. Então, se para a maior soma de quadrados de dígitos com `n` dígitos ela for menor do que o menor número de `n` dígitos, então temos que `10^(n-1)` será um limite superior a essa soma, portanto não haverá laços com elemetos maiores que `10^(n-1)`. Isso também limitado o tamanho máximo do laço para `10^(n-1)`.

Peguemos com `n = 4`. O menor número é `1000`. A maior soma é `4*81 = 324`. Isso significa que qualquer soma feita com 4 dígitos ou menos será sempre limitada a 324. Isso implica que não haverá laços com mais do que 1000 elementos, com todos os elementos limitados a no máximo o número 1000.

> Ok, o limite na verdade é bem menor, mas o limite relaxado já é o suficiente para a demonstração

Pegando essa ideia, podemos fazer a função `feliz` que faz uma verificação recursiva pela felicidade dos números. Para isso, uso um "*caminho de migalhas*" que, sempre que toco nele, detecto o laço e portanto a infelicidade do número. Também aproveito conhecimento prévio da felicidade alheia e se a soma dos quadrados dos dígitos já for conhecidamente `feliz` ou `infeliz` e marco meu caminho de volta com essa medida de felicidade.

No caso, minha memória é posicional e cada posição consiste de um estado. Existem 4 possíveis estados:

- `undefined`: memória nova, não tenho nada memoizado para essa posição
- `'H'`: feliz =)
- `'M'`: triste =/
- `'S'`: minha migalha, não sei ainda

Note que para a memoização funcionar corretamente, esse caminho de migalhas impede a execução paralela de descobrimento de novas memórias. Se com essa memoização alguém colocar esse algoritmo para servir duas perguntas sobre a felicidade dos números em paralelo, o resultado não será garantido. E a partir desse ponto a memória deve ser limpa para começar de novo.

Um detalhe importante é que a memoização aqui começa com o caso base já na memória: eu já começo lembrando que `1 ==> 'H'`.

Segue a versão mais legível, com *trace* para verificar a memória e apenas alguns poucos números testados:

```js
function soma_quad_digits(numero) {
  let soma_quad = 0;
  while (numero > 0) {
    let dig = numero % 10;
    numero = Math.floor(numero/10);
    soma_quad += dig*dig;
  }
  return soma_quad;
}

function felicidade_memoizada(numero, memoria) {
  if (memoria[numero] === undefined) {
    console.log("indo atrás da felicidade de " + numero + " (soma do quadrado dos dígitos: " + soma_quad_digits(numero) + ")");
    // memória aqui é indefinida! oba \o/
    memoria[numero] = 'S'; // S de SEARCHING, usado pra marcar loops
    let nova_memoria = felicidade_memoizada(soma_quad_digits(numero), memoria); // busca a nova memória recursivamente
    memoria[numero] = nova_memoria; // fazendo a memoização
    console.log("memorizando que " + numero + " é " + nova_memoria);
    return nova_memoria;
  } else if (memoria[numero] == 'H') { // H de HAPPY
    return 'H'; // sim, achou memória feliz
  } else if (memoria[numero] == 'M') { // M de MAD
    return 'M'; // caí num caso conhecido de infelicidade
  } else if (memoria[numero] == 'S') { // oh, oh... loop
    // nesse caso, na recursão que preencheu como SEARCHING originalmente  vai marcar esse cara como MAD...
    return 'M';
  }
}

let memoria = [];
memoria[1] = 'H'; // definição

let feliz = (n) => felicidade_memoizada(n, memoria) == 'H';

console.log(feliz(2));
console.log(feliz(7));
console.log(feliz(19));
console.log(feliz(23));
console.log(feliz(50));
```

Agora, poderíamos ter de modo mais elegante a criação da função `feliz`. Não gostei muito de deixar a variável `memoria` no escopo global. Podemos usar uma função [autoinvocada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13365/64969) que retorna a função `feliz`. Essa versão eu já sacrifico logo todos os comentários e legibilidade:

```js
let feliz = (function() {
  function soma_quad_digits(numero) {
    let soma_quad = 0;
    for (let dig = numero % 10; numero > 0; numero = (numero/10)|0, dig = numero%10) {
      soma_quad += dig*dig;
    }
    return soma_quad;
  }

  function felicidade_memoizada(numero, memoria) {
    if (numero > 10000) {
      return felicidade_memoizada(soma_quad_digits(numero), memoria);
    }
    if (memoria[numero] === undefined) {
      memoria[numero] = 'S';
      return memoria[numero] = felicidade_memoizada(soma_quad_digits(numero), memoria);
    } else if (memoria[numero] == 'H') {
      return 'H';
    } else {
      return 'M';
    }
  }

  let memoria = [];
  memoria[1] = 'H';

  return (n) => felicidade_memoizada(n, memoria) == 'H';
})();

for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
  if (feliz(i)) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Mas, sinceramente, por que nos limitar a apenas 50? Vamos até o limite superior *relaxado* do laço, que seria 1000?

```js
let feliz = (function() {
  function soma_quad_digits(numero) {
    let soma_quad = 0;
    for (let dig = numero % 10; numero > 0; numero = (numero/10)|0, dig = numero%10) {
      soma_quad += dig*dig;
    }
    return soma_quad;
  }

  function felicidade_memoizada(numero, memoria) {
    if (numero > 10000) {
      return felicidade_memoizada(soma_quad_digits(numero), memoria);
    }
    if (memoria[numero] === undefined) {
      memoria[numero] = 'S';
      return memoria[numero] = felicidade_memoizada(soma_quad_digits(numero), memoria);
    } else if (memoria[numero] == 'H') {
      return 'H';
    } else {
      return 'M';
    }
  }

  let memoria = [];
  memoria[1] = 'H';

  return (n) => felicidade_memoizada(n, memoria) == 'H';
})();

for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
  if (feliz(i)) {
    document.write(i + " "); // tentei ficar só no log, mas ficou grande demais...
  }
}
```