# A soma de todos os números ímpares não primos que antecedem a um inteiro?

Tags: c

Exemplo 1 de execução:

```
Entrada ( numero inteiro): 10
```

Saída: 10

Até agora tenho isso:

```
num =10;

for (i = 2; i < num ; i++)

   {

    if (num % i == 1 ){

        printf("%d\n", i);

        soma2 = i + soma2;


    }
}
```

Porém na saída aparece:
3 e 9 e não somente o 9.

Comment: Não primos são 1, 4, 6, 8, 9, ímpares = 1, 9, a soma seria 10 não?

Answer (score 3):

A forma mais simples de se implementar é:

1. Lê o número n;
2. Inicia soma como zero;
3. Percorre o intervalo [1, n] em k;
4. Verifica se k é um número primo. Se sim, volta para 3; se não continua;
5. Verifica se o número é ímpar. Se não, volta para 3; se sim, continua;
6. Soma o valor de k em soma;
7. Exibe resultado;

Mas a solução não escala muito bem a medida que o valor de n cresça. A função que verifica se é primo teria complexidade O(n) e a função implementada chamaria tal função n vezes, o que resultaria em uma solução O(n²).

Para uma solução melhor escalável, você pode verificar o problema do ponto de vista matemático (pois é um problema matemático, certo?). Encontrar os números primos em um intervalo fechado é relativamente simples quando implementado o crivo de Eratóstenes e calcular a soma deles também será algo trivial. Desta forma, se você deseja a soma de todos os números ímpares não primos no intervalo, basta você calcular a soma de todos os números ímpares e subtrair a soma dos números primos (não esqueça que o 2 é primo, mas é par).

É possível demonstrar que a soma de todos os números ímpares no intervalo [1, n] é dada por m², sendo m a quantidade de números ímpares do intervalo. Se n é ímpar, m = (n+1)/2 e se n é par, m = n/2. Genericamente falando, m = (n + n % 2)/2. Portanto, sabemos que a soma de todos os números ímpares será ((n + n % 2)/2)², que é uma operação O(1), não depende da dimensão de n, possui sempre o mesmo número de operações.

Após isso, podemos calcular a soma dos números primos no intervalo [1, n]:

- [Soma de primos em um intervalo em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/310945/5878)

E para obter o resultado desejado, fazemos a soma de todos os números ímpares subtraindo a soma de todos os números ímpares (e adicionando o 2, que é primo mas não é ímpar). Portanto, o algoritmo passaria a ser:

1. Lê o número n;
2. Calcula a soma de todos os números ímpares no intervalo [1, n];
3. Calcula a soma de todos os números primos no intervalo [1, n];
4. A soma de todos os ímpares não primos será: soma<sub>ímpares</sub> - soma<sub>primos</sub> + 2;
5. Exibe o resultado;

E, desta forma, você terá uma solução muito mais escalável que a primeira alternativa.

Para n = 10, teríamos:

- Soma de todos os ímpares: 25
- Soma de todos os primos: 17
- Resultado: 25 - 17 + 2 = 10

**Leituras adicionais:**

- [Como gerar 200.000 primos o mais rápido possível em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231555/5878)

Answer (score 0):

Algo deste género:

```
num = 10;
soma = 0;

for(int i = 2; i < num; i++){ 
    if(!isEven(i) && !isPrime(i)){
        soma += soma;
    } 
}
```

> Lista de alguns números primos:
>
> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61,
>   67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137,
>   139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211,
>   223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283,
>   293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379,
>   383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461,
>   463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563,
>   569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643,
>   647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739,
>   743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829,
>   839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937,
>   941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997

Não sei qual é o seu objetivo a nível de performance, mas se apenas precisar que o algoritmo funcione com limitação da entrada pode utilizar dados fixos de números primos ou a lista dos números ímpares não primos.
Desta maneira só teria de realizar um loop pelos números e filtrar pelos valores menores que a sua entrada.

No caso da entrada 10 percorria os dados fixos e encontrava os inteiros não primos ímpares 1 e 9, depois somava cada um destes e o resultado seria 10.

Outra maneira seria ir criando números e verificando se são números não primos e se são ímpares, caso sejam vai acumulando o valor numa variável até chegar ao seu limite superior (valor de entrada).

Comment: Certo, estou iniciante, poderia me demonstrar como percorrer para achar os números não primos, até 10 (usuário digitou), sendo maior que 1, então no caso, só entraria o 9.

Comment: atualizei a minha resposta com um exemplo melhor do que vc quer, agora tem de implementar apenas o isEven e o isPrime.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve implementar o algoritmo [Crivo de Eratóstenes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crivo_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes) em seu código, e guardar num array os números que não passarem pelo crivo.

Depois disso você percorre o array com os números que não passaram pelo crivo, somando os valores.

É isso.