# Quando usar o Lazy<> do C#

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-loading

Onde é um bom cenário para se utilizar o inicializador `Lazy<>` do C#?

Pergunto isso porque, entendo o conceito por trás do *lazy loading* (atrasar a instância de um objeto para apenas quando o mesmo for necessário), mas ainda não tive a necessidade de usar, por isso gostaria de um exemplo de uma boa situação de onde implementar.

Por exemplo, lendo a documentação aqui: [lazy inicialization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization)

Há dois exemplos:

> "When you have an object that is expensive to create, and the program
>   might not use it"

ou em tradução livre,

> "Quando  tem um objeto que é custoso para ser criado e pode não ser
>   usado"

Neste caso, bastaria usar um simples `if` nem ao mesmo criá-lo a menos que vai usar, correto?

> "When you have an object that is expensive to create, and you want to
>   defer its creation until after other expensive operations have been
>   completed"

ou em tradução livre

> "Quando você tem um objeto que é custoso para ser criado e deseja
>   adiar sua criação até que outras operações custosas tenham sido
>   concluídas"

Posso apenas mudar o local onde o objeto foi criado, fazer isso de forma assíncrona, em outra *thread*, etc, ou seja, várias formas de contornar isso.

Queria um exemplo de uma situação onde realmente o `Lazy` faria a diferença, que resolveria se ter a necessidade de muita implementação, ou algo complexo para contornar o problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que não está tão claro em tudo isto já exposto é que esta classe deveria ser usada sempre que o dado pode ou não ser usado na execução do momento. Não é só questão de deixar para depois, é deixar para depois porque quem sabe pode nem ser necessário.

Acho que ficou claro que só vale a pena fazer isto se a inicialização é cara, portanto vem de uma operação cara de um banco de dados, ou da internet ou serviço que você não tem controle do tempo gasto. É tipo o uso de `async`, só vale a pena se a operação demora.

Em geral campos de uma estrutura são inicializados no momento de sua criação então qualquer situação que aquilo pode ou não ser usado pode ser útil.

Mas é preciso cuidado porque as pessoas podem começar usar isto para compensar *design* ruim. Há situação que o que pode ou não ser usado, e portanto atrasado, deva fazer parte de outro objeto.

## Exemplos

O exemplo mais comum de uso deste tipo é em ORMs já que o dado pode ou não ser usado então seria melhor não pedir ao DB de imediato. Por outro lado, e esta é uma das críticas que se faz ao ORM, isto pode prejudicar a performance porque faz ter mais acessos ao banco de dados em vez de trazer tudo de uma vez só. Claro que normalmente você tem isso pronto e não usa o `Lazy` no seu código, a não ser que esteja fazendo um ORM, e mesmo assim pode ser que até prefira um mecanismo mais sofisticado de controle, [`Lazy` é bem simples](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Lazy.cs,8b99c1f377873554).

Eu achei um [exemplo no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16956400/221800) que mostra bem que tudo que usa o `Lazy` dá para fazer sem ele:

```
public sealed class Singleton {
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> instanceHolder = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());
    private Singleton() { ... }
    public static Singleton Instance => instanceHolder.Value;
}
```

E sem:

```
private static object lockingObject = new object();
public static LazySample InstanceCreation() {
    if (lazilyInitObject == null) {
        lock (lockingObject) {
            if (lazilyInitObject == null) lazilyInitObject = new LazySample();
        }
    }
    return lazilyInitObject;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/Lazy.cs).

Não sei se o exemplo é tão bom para mostrar a prática (o objetivo não era esse) porque o objeto só é criado quando se chama uma vez e neste caso normalmente quando chama já precisa ser usado.

É o mesmo caso de uso local (método), você pode colocar no momento que precisa. Não digo que nunca deva usar, mas em geral não precisa do `Lazy`. A necessidade desse tipo tem mais a ver com o fato de você não saber o exato momento que precisa. Quase todos exemplos de uso local é só para demonstrar o mecanismo e não a prática de uso.

Se você tem um objeto estático pode ser útil porque por especificação a inicialização desse objeto pode ser feita em qualquer momento desde a inicialização da aplicação até o o uso desse objeto. O `Lazy` seria uma forma de garantir que a inicialização efetiva só ocorra no momento de uso.

Isto ocorre porque a inicialização formal ocorre sem seu controle, mas o que é inicializado é objeto `Lazy` que é muito barato, e o objeto que importa (o `T`) será inicializado quando for usado, O `Lazy` controla isto.

Então tentando dar um uso prático, pense que você acessa os dados de um correntista de banco. Em geral você só acesso os dados da conta, mas em alguns casos poderá acessar as transações dele, mas por alguma razão a lista dessas transações foram colocadas na conta provavelmente para facilitar o acesso e não ter um objeto externo.

```
public Lazy<IList<Transacoes>> trancasoes => new Lazy<IList<Transacoes>>(() => ObtemTranscaoes(this.Id));
```

Parto de pressuposto que este método demora para ser executado.

É um bom exemplo? Eu acho que não porque parece ser *design* ruim apenas, mas se teve algum motivo de manter as transações junto da conta então faz sentido. A maioria dos exemplos que encontramos não é necessário mesmo.

Um exemplo que pode ser útil é quando há [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33438/101). Mas também pode abusar disto e em muitos casos precisa de uma sofisticação que o `Lazy` não resolve. Em outros o tempo que ele gasta é irrisório para precisar da inicialização preguiçosa.

É como *design pattern* (o que isto é já pronto para uso fornecido pela biblioteca), você deve saber que existe, mas não sair aplicando porque existe. Nos raros casos que deve ser usado você tem conhecimento e verá que ali se aplica, ou então que o seu *design* está ruim e deve repensá-lo.

Comment: hum ainda estou lendo tudo, mas esse exemplo do Singleton é bem interessante, código bem mais limpo

Comment: Manieiro, isso me deu até uma ideia: imagina que tem uma Strategy que cria instâncias de classes, ou uma cadeia de métodos, qualquer coisa assim, e essa Strategy pode demorar ou até nunca ser usada, talvez seria uma boa aplicação para o Lazy na criação das instâncias, faz sentido?

Comment: Não sei se entendi ou se está claro os detalhes de como isso ocorreria, mas um objeto deveria ter uma só estratégia. Você tem várias estratégias possíveis, mas só uma delas seria usada (pelo menos olhando para um aspecto daquele objeto). Então não tem porque criar as outras, por isso não precisa inicializar, não é questão de inicializar depois. A não ser que esteja falando de que mesmo a estratégia escolhida pode não ser usada, aí independe de ser uma estratégia, é o mesmo exemplo que usei com esse `IList`, e pode ser *design* errado. E se estiver falando que dentro da estratégia pode ter um

Comment: `Lazy` pra algo dele, nada tem a ver com o mecanismo de estratégia, e sim essa em específico por acaso pode precisar disto.

Comment: acho que não expliquei bem, vou tentar montar um código para deixar mais claro

Answer (score 1):

Talvez uma situação que eu vejo que isso possa ser bem útil e utilizavel seja com Func/Delegate, onde você pode passar um objeto Lazy que você poderá ou não usar ele dentro da sua Func.

Sendo assim, dentro dela você poderia fazer as devidas validações para iniciar ou não ele tal como também a manipulação, porém, há outras formas de contornar isso, mas essa é uma maneira bem aplicável.