# Como evitar que um elemento seja processado mais de uma vez na função de comparação de Array.prototype.sort?

Tags: javascript, array, desempenho, classificação, otimização

No [método `Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) podemos usar uma função de comparação, que por sua vez pode processar os elementos para que a comparação seja feita de acordo com critérios customizados.

Porém, reparei que isso pode acarretar em uma certa redundância no processamento. Por exemplo, neste código:

```js
function getSortKey(item) {
    console.log('getSortKey', item);
    return parseInt(item);
}

const array = ['4', '16', '8', '2', '6'];
array.sort((a, b) => getSortKey(a) - getSortKey(b));

console.log(array);
```

Criei a função `getSortKey` apenas para saber quando determinada string é convertida para número durante a ordenação. O resultado foi:

```
getSortKey 16
getSortKey 4
getSortKey 8
getSortKey 16
getSortKey 8
getSortKey 16
getSortKey 8
getSortKey 4
getSortKey 2
getSortKey 8
getSortKey 2
getSortKey 4
getSortKey 6
getSortKey 8
getSortKey 6
getSortKey 4
[ '2', '4', '6', '8', '16' ]
```

Ou seja, todos os elementos foram processados por `getSortKey` mais de uma vez (o que seria redundante e desnecessário, já que cada string sempre resulta no mesmo número).

<sup>*Obs: teste feito no Chrome. Diferentes *browsers*/*runtimes*/implementações podem usar algoritmos de ordenação diferentes, e portanto a saída exata pode variar (mas testando em outros browsers, notei que o problema também ocorre: a função sendo chamada várias vezes para os mesmos elementos).*</sup>

---

## O problema

O exemplo acima foi apenas "didático", feito com o intuito de demonstrar que a função `getSortKey` é chamada várias vezes para os mesmos elementos.

Mas **vamos supor** que `getSortKey` seja uma operação mais cara/demorada, que o array tenha muitos elementos e o fato desta função ser chamada várias vezes para os mesmos elementos seja um gargalo que deva ser eliminado.

**O ideal seria que `getSortKey` processasse cada elemento apenas uma vez. Como fazer isso?**

---

Obs: vale lembrar que o exemplo acima é ilustrativo, e as soluções devem contemplar qualquer tipo de elemento e função. Por exemplo, um array de objetos que devem ser ordenados a partir do processamento de um de seus campos:

```js
function getDate(str) {
    console.log('getDate', str);
    return new Date(str);
}

const array = [
  { nome: 'Fulano',   dtNasc: '2000-01-10' },
  { nome: 'Ciclano',  dtNasc: '1980-11-04' },
  { nome: 'Beltrano', dtNasc: '2010-03-11' },
  { nome: 'Trajano',  dtNasc: '2001-05-20' }
];
// ordenar pela data de nascimento (getDate precisa converter as strings para Date)
array.sort((a, b) => getDate(a.dtNasc) - getDate(b.dtNasc));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: E mais uma vez, antes que alguém estranhe que eu mesmo respondi minha própria pergunta, isso é [**perfeitamente aceitável e dentro das regras**](/help/self-answer). Inclusive, a [página de fazer pergunta](/questions/ask) tem uma [opção para postar a própria resposta juntamente com a pergunta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPEQw.png). Claro que se alguém tiver uma resposta melhor e mais completa, ou outras formas de resolver, com certeza deve postá-la. O objetivo é trazer este conhecimento para o site (pois fiz uma busca e não tinha encontrado nada a respeito).

Comment: Achei que haveriam mais votos, o assunto é interessante pois trata-se de um problema comum as implementações nativas do algoritmo de classificação Quicksort em várias linguagens e as optimizações mostradas aqui podem facilmente serem portadas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***Obs**: para arrays pequenos e/ou quando a função é relativamente rápida e não interfere no desempenho, nada disso é realmente necessário, já que a diferença será imperceptível (ver análise no final). Dito isso, vamos à solução.*

Vou sugerir duas formas de garantir que a função `getSortKey` processe cada elemento apenas uma vez: [memoização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33438/112052) e [transformação de Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) (*Schwartzian transform*).

---

## Memoização

A ideia da memoização é guardar os resultados que já foram computados anteriormente, e caso a função seja chamada novamente com os mesmos argumentos, retorna-se esse valor guardado, em vez de calculá-lo de novo (que é justamente o que queremos, evitar que o valor seja calculado novamente). Um jeito simples de fazer seria:

```js
var computed = {};
function getSortKeyMem(item) {
    if (!computed[item]) {
        console.log('getSortKey', item); // logar somente quando o valor é calculado
        computed[item] = parseInt(item);
    }
    return computed[item];
}

let array = ['4', '16', '8', '2', '6'];
array.sort((a, b) => getSortKeyMem(a) - getSortKeyMem(b));
console.log(array);
```

A saída é:

```
getSortKey 16
getSortKey 4
getSortKey 8
getSortKey 2
getSortKey 6
[ '2', '4', '6', '8', '16' ]
```

Ou seja, cada elemento só foi processado uma vez. Nas demais vezes, usou-se o valor que foi previamente guardado.

> Claro que [existem formas mais sofisticadas de fazer](http://cangaceirojavascript.com.br/funcoes-velozes-com-memoization-pattern/), mas o foco aqui não é "*a melhor maneira de implementar memoização*", e sim mostrar que se usá-la, cada elemento só é processado uma vez.

---

## Transformação de Schwartz

A [transformação de Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) (*Schwartzian transform*) também é conhecida como (ou inspirada pelo) padrão *decorate-sort-undecorate* do Lisp.

Basicamente, consiste em primeiro computar o valor da função (no caso, `getSortKey`) para todos os elementos, apenas uma vez para cada, e colocar os resultados no próprio array (ou gerar um outro array temporário) - esta é a etapa de *decorate*. Depois, faz-se a ordenação usando esses valores computados (etapa de *sort*). Por fim, os valores computados são removidos, restando apenas os elementos originais, agora ordenados (etapa de *undecorate*).

Usando a mesma função acima (mas sem memoização), e aplicando a transformação de Schwartz, ficaria assim:

```js
function getSortKey(item) {
    console.log('getSortKey', item);
    return parseInt(item);
}

const array = ['4', '16', '8', '2', '6'];

// decorate: computa a chave para cada elemento e guarda no próprio array
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = [ array[i], getSortKey(array[i]) ];
}

// ordena usando o valor computado
array.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);

// undecorate: remove as chaves, deixando apenas os elementos originais
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i][0];
}

console.log(array);
```

Agora a saída é:

```
getSortKey 4
getSortKey 16
getSortKey 8
getSortKey 2
getSortKey 6
[ '2', '4', '6', '8', '16' ]
```

Ou seja, `getSortKey` foi chamada apenas uma vez para cada elemento. Claro que se o array tivesse elementos repetidos, ainda sim teríamos chamadas redundantes, mas de qualquer forma já é melhor do que sempre recalcular o valor (e claro que isto poderia ser resolvido com memoização, mas enfim).

No primeiro `for` eu substituo cada elemento por um array contendo o próprio elemento e o respectivo resultado de `getSortKey`. No `sort` eu uso esses resultados como critério de ordenação, e no segundo `for` eu removo-os, deixando apenas os elementos originais. O que sobra é o array devidamente ordenado.

Outra alternativa é usar um objeto em vez de um array na fase de *decorate*, deixando o código mais claro:

```js
function getSortKey(item) {
    console.log('getSortKey', item);
    return parseInt(item);
}

const array = ['4', '16', '8', '2', '6'];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // objeto em vez de array
    array[i] = { original: array[i], sortKey: getSortKey(array[i]) };
}
array.sort((a, b) => a.sortKey - b.sortKey);
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i].original;
}
console.log(array);
```

Testando com o último exemplo da pergunta:

```js
function getDate(str) {
    console.log('getDate', str);
    return new Date(str);
}

const array = [
  { nome: 'Fulano',   dtNasc: '2000-01-10' },
  { nome: 'Ciclano',  dtNasc: '1980-11-04' },
  { nome: 'Beltrano', dtNasc: '2010-03-11' },
  { nome: 'Trajano',  dtNasc: '2001-05-20' }
];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = { original: array[i], sortKey: getDate(array[i].dtNasc) };
}
array.sort((a, b) => a.sortKey - b.sortKey);
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i].original;
}
console.log(array);
```

---

Também é possível usar `map` para criar outro array no primeiro e terceiro passos:

```js
function getSortKey(item) {
    console.log('getSortKey', item);
    return parseInt(item);
}

let array = ['4', '16', '8', '2', '6'];
array = array
    // decorate: computa a chave para cada elemento e guarda no próprio array
    .map(e => [ e, getSortKey(e) ])
    // ordena usando o valor computado
    .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
    // undecorate: remove as chaves, deixando apenas os elementos originais
    .map(e => e[0]);

console.log(array);
```

O problema é que cada chamada de `map` cria um novo array (além, é claro, dos subarrays que já estamos criando para cada par `[ e, getSortKey(e) ]`, mas esses têm que ser criados de qualquer jeito), o que torna esta versão menos eficiente em termos de consumo de memória.

---

Também é possível generalizar a solução com Schwartz para qualquer array (adicionando-o no protótipo, por exemplo, e [levando-se em conta todos os poréns de fazê-lo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034242)), podendo receber a função como parâmetro, e comparando os próprios elementos em caso de empate no resultado da função (que pode ou não fazer parte do critério; no exemplo abaixo, faz, nos exemplos acima, não). Código retirado [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124053):

```js
function getSortKey(item) {
    console.log('getSortKey', item);
    return parseInt(item);
}

(function(){
  if (typeof Object.defineProperty === 'function'){
    try{Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'sortBy',{value:sb}); }catch(e){}
  }
  if (!Array.prototype.sortBy) Array.prototype.sortBy = sb;

  function sb(f){
    for (var i=this.length;i;){
      var o = this[--i];
      this[i] = [].concat(f.call(o,o,i),o);
    }
    this.sort(function(a,b){
      for (var i=0,len=a.length;i<len;++i){
        if (a[i]!=b[i]) return a[i]<b[i]?-1:1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    for (var i=this.length;i;){
      this[--i]=this[i][this[i].length-1];
    }
    return this;
  }
})();

let array = ['4', '16', '8', '2', '6'];
console.log(array.sortBy(getSortKey));
```

---

## Testes

Fiz um [teste básico no JSBench](https://jsbench.me/tokzh1it6r/1) usando o Chrome, e o mesmo teste na minha máquina usando o [Benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/).

Na minha máquina a solução com memoização se mostrou bem mais rápida, e as soluções com Schwartz ficaram em segundo lugar (geralmente com as soluções sem `map` sendo ligeiramente melhores). No browser as soluções com Schwartz foram mais rápidas (e não usar `map` também se mostrou um pouco mais rápido), enquanto memoização ficou em segundo. O ponto em comum é que usar `sort` "puro" (sem Schwartz e sem memoização) sempre foi mais lento.

Mas como já dito no início, isso só faz alguma diferença para uma função que seja relativamente cara/demorada e com um array que tenha muitos elementos. Para um array pequeno e/ou usando uma função simples e rápida, toda a manipulação feita nas etapas de *decorate* e *undecorate* acabou deixando até mais lento do que um `sort` sem Schwartz, e usar memoização não fez muita diferença (na verdade ficou mais lento, provavelmente pelo custo adicional de verificar se o valor já foi computado, que realmente não se paga nesses casos). Ou seja, como tudo em computação, deve-se avaliar caso a caso se realmente precisa usar estas soluções.

Comment: +1, porém: _"adicionando-o no protótipo"_ [.](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jjskLlGUNp4/maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: @CmteCardeal Bom, é só uma alternativa, claro que vc pode fazer como uma função separada (o que eu também prefiro). Gostei do link escondido :-)