# Como ordeno um objeto com base na ordem de um array?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, classificação

Eu tenho o seguinte array de objetos:

```
0: {food: 'dessert', name: 'sagu de tangerina'}
1: {food: 'garnish2', name: 'moranga refogada com bacon'}
2: {food: 'salad2', name: 'pimentão colorido'}
3: {food: 'rice', name: 'arroz'}
4: {food: 'brownRice', name: 'arroz integral'}
5: {food: 'salad4', name: 'beterraba ralada'}
6: {food: 'salad3', name: 'agrião com manga'}
7: {food: 'meat2', name: 'filezinho de frango empanado'}
8: {food: 'cutFruit', name: 'melancia'}
9: {food: 'meat1', name: 'dobradinha'}
10: {food: 'salad1', name: 'escarola frisse'}
11: {food: 'bean', name: 'feijão'}
12: {food: 'garnish1', name: 'batata rustica II'}
13: {food: 'salad5', name: 'chucrute caseiro'}
14: {food: 'meat3', name: 'ovo assado'}
15: {food: 'extra-garnish2', name: 'Bacon para G2'}
16: {food: 'extra-dessert1', name: 'Pudim prestigio'}
17: {food: 'extra-salad2', name: 'Acelga'}
18: {food: 'extra-meat2', name: 'Filezinho fgo empanado ( reg.)'}
19: {food: 'extra-garnish3', name: 'Macarrão  a Siliciana ( reg.)'}
20: {food: 'extra-meat1', name: 'Escalope ao molho sugo ( reg.)'}
21: {food: 'extra-salad1', name: 'Radite'}
```

E eu tenho que ordenar ele com base na tag FOOD, na seguinte ordem:

```
let orderBy = ["salad", "cutFruit", "dessert", "syrup", "coldSauce", "hotSauce", "garnish", "rice", "bean", "meat"];
```

Mas não estou conseguindo pensar em muita coisa. Tentei da seguinte forma, porém não funcionou:

```
let orderBy = ["salad", "cutFruit", "dessert", "syrup", "coldSauce", "hotSauce", "garnish", "rice", "bean", "meat"];
food.sort((a, b) => {
    let fa = a.food.toLowerCase(),
        fb = b.food.toLowerCase();

    orderBy.forEach(function (order, i) {
        if (fa.includes(orderBy[i]) && fb.includes(orderBy[i+1])) {
            return -1;
        }else if(fa.includes(orderBy[i+1]) && fb.includes(orderBy[i])){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    })

    // return fa < fb ? -1 : fa > fb ? 1 : 0;
});
```

---

Consegui resolver esse problema com as respostas, só tive que modificar um pouco e ficou assim:

```
let orderBy = ["salad", "coldSauce", "hotSauce", "garnish", "rice", "bean", "meat", "dessert", "syrup", "cutFruit", "juice"];
const foodOrderly= [];

orderBy.forEach(function (order) {
    food.forEach(function (point) {
        if (point.food.includes(order)) {
            foodOrderly.push(point);
        }
    });
});
```

Único detalhe é que ele vem todo desorganizado, como: salad3, salad1, extra-salad2...

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma coisa que não ficou clara é o que fazer com os valores que não estão no array `orderBy` (como o "extra-meat", "extra-salad", etc). Eles devem estar no resultado final? Em caso afirmativo, em qual ordem? Eles também devem ser ordenados entre si?

De qualquer forma, a ideia básica é que você pode usar o próprio método `sort`, em vez de fazer vários loops aninhados (que não só é mais ineficiente, como é uma complicação desnecessária). O método `sort` pode receber uma função de comparação, e aí dentro dela você coloca os critérios que quiser.

No caso o critério básico é obter o tipo de comida e uma numeração opcional (por exemplo, em "salad1" o tipo é "salad" e o número é 1, já em "salad" o tipo é "salad", mas não tem número - e nesse caso, entendi que ele vem antes de todos, então podemos colocar o número zero).

Já os itens que não estão no array `orderBy` (como o "extra-salad") estou colocando no final, sem ordenação específica entre eles. E caso eles não devam estar no resultado final, é bem simples removê-los depois.

Então primeiro criamos um objeto que mapeia cada tipo de comida com a sua respectiva posição no array `orderBy`. Caso o tipo não esteja em `orderBy`, estou colocando ele no final (ou seja, os "extra-*" ficarão no final, e sem uma ordenação específica).

Mas também coloco uma opção que remove-os do array, se for o caso.

```js
const arrayFood = [
  {food: 'dessert', name: 'sagu de tangerina'},
  {food: 'garnish2', name: 'moranga refogada com bacon'},
  {food: 'salad2', name: 'pimentão colorido'},
  {food: 'rice', name: 'arroz'},
  {food: 'brownRice', name: 'arroz integral'},
  {food: 'salad4', name: 'beterraba ralada'},
  {food: 'salad3', name: 'agrião com manga'},
  {food: 'meat2', name: 'filezinho de frango empanado'},
  {food: 'cutFruit', name: 'melancia'},
  {food: 'meat1', name: 'dobradinha'},
  {food: 'salad1', name: 'escarola frisse'},
  {food: 'bean', name: 'feijão'},
  {food: 'garnish1', name: 'batata rustica II'},
  {food: 'salad5', name: 'chucrute caseiro'},
  {food: 'meat3', name: 'ovo assado'},
  {food: 'extra-garnish2', name: 'Bacon para G2'},
  {food: 'extra-dessert1', name: 'Pudim prestigio'},
  {food: 'extra-salad2', name: 'Acelga'},
  {food: 'extra-meat2', name: 'Filezinho fgo empanado ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-garnish3', name: 'Macarrão  a Siliciana ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-meat1', name: 'Escalope ao molho sugo ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-salad1', name: 'Radite'},
];

let orderBy = ["salad", "cutFruit", "dessert", "syrup", "coldSauce", "hotSauce", "garnish", "rice", "bean", "meat"];
// mapeia cada tipo com o seu respectivo índice no array orderBy    
const ordemIndices = {};
for (var i = 0; i < orderBy.length; i++) {
    ordemIndices[orderBy[i]] = i;
}

// obtém o número do tipo (ou zero, caso não tenha), e a posição do tipo no array orderBy
function getSortInfo(food, ordemIndices, criterioTipoNumero) {
    let [type, number] = food.match(criterioTipoNumero).slice(1, 3);
    if (! number)
        number = 0;
    // se o tipo está no array orderBy, retorna a posição deste, senão retorna um número grande (pois ele estará no final)
    let pos = ordemIndices.hasOwnProperty(type) ? parseInt(ordemIndices[type]) : Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    return [parseInt(number), pos];
}

const criterioTipoNumero = /^([-a-z]+)(\d*)/i;
arrayFood.sort(function(a, b) {
    var [numA, indexA] = getSortInfo(a.food, ordemIndices, criterioTipoNumero);
    var [numB, indexB] = getSortInfo(b.food, ordemIndices, criterioTipoNumero);
    // primeiro verifica a posição do tipo no array orderBy
    let cmp = indexA - indexB;
    // se a posição é igual, o desempate é pelo número
    if (cmp === 0) {
        cmp = numA - numB;
    }
    return cmp;
});
// array ordenado, e os itens que não estão em orderBy (como os "extra-*") ficam no final
console.log('----------\nordenado com todos\n', arrayFood);

//------------------------------------------------------------
// se for para remover o que não está no array orderBy
const ordenado = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arrayFood.length; i++) {
    if (ordemIndices.hasOwnProperty(arrayFood[i].food.match(criterioTipoNumero)[1])) {
        ordenado.push(arrayFood[i]);
    } else {
        // como arrayFood está ordenado, e os que não estão em orderBy ficam no final,
        // posso interromper quando encontrar o primeiro que não está
        break;
    }
}
console.log('------------\nsomente os que estão em orderBy\n', ordenado);
```

---

Desta forma fica - **na minha opinião** - mais claro o que está sendo feito (um `sort`, cujo critério fica descrito na função passada como argumento; e se for o caso, a remoção dos objetos que não estão em `orderBy`).

E como curiosidade, [esta opção é mais rápida](https://jsbench.me/aul8d7ekwn/1) que as outras sugestões -  e conforme o array `orderBy` aumenta, [a diferença se torna ainda mais gritante](https://jsbench.me/90l8d98hbl/1).

Claro que para poucos arrays pequenos, a diferença é imperceptível ([para poucos dados, tudo é rápido](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/)), mas ainda sim acho que usar `sort` da maneira como foi concebido não só fica mais claro, como ainda permite [esta otimização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/542601/112052), caso seja necessário.

---

## Incluir os "extras" na ordenação

Nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/565288/como-ordeno-um-objeto-com-base-na-ordem-de-um-array/565328#comment998949_565328) foi dito que os "extras" devem ser inclusos e ordenados depois dos "não-extras" (ou seja, ficaria "salad1", "salad2", "extra-salad1", "extra-salad2", etc). Então teria que mudar um pouco (mas veja que alteração não é muito grande, pois basta mudar a lógica da função passada para `sort`):

```js
const arrayFood = [
  {food: 'dessert', name: 'sagu de tangerina'},
  {food: 'garnish2', name: 'moranga refogada com bacon'},
  {food: 'salad2', name: 'pimentão colorido'},
  {food: 'rice', name: 'arroz'},
  {food: 'brownRice', name: 'arroz integral'},
  {food: 'salad4', name: 'beterraba ralada'},
  {food: 'salad3', name: 'agrião com manga'},
  {food: 'meat2', name: 'filezinho de frango empanado'},
  {food: 'cutFruit', name: 'melancia'},
  {food: 'meat1', name: 'dobradinha'},
  {food: 'salad1', name: 'escarola frisse'},
  {food: 'bean', name: 'feijão'},
  {food: 'garnish1', name: 'batata rustica II'},
  {food: 'salad5', name: 'chucrute caseiro'},
  {food: 'meat3', name: 'ovo assado'},
  {food: 'extra-garnish2', name: 'Bacon para G2'},
  {food: 'extra-dessert1', name: 'Pudim prestigio'},
  {food: 'extra-salad2', name: 'Acelga'},
  {food: 'extra-meat2', name: 'Filezinho fgo empanado ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-garnish3', name: 'Macarrão  a Siliciana ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-meat1', name: 'Escalope ao molho sugo ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-salad1', name: 'Radite'},
];

let orderBy = ["salad", "cutFruit", "dessert", "syrup", "coldSauce", "hotSauce", "garnish", "rice", "bean", "meat"];

// obtém o número do tipo (ou zero, caso não tenha), e a posição do tipo no array orderBy, e a informação se tem "extra"
function getSortInfo(food, ordemIndices, criterioTipoNumero) {
    let [extra, type, number] = food.match(criterioTipoNumero).slice(1, 4);
    if (! number)
        number = 0;
    // se o tipo está no array, retorna a posição, senão retorna um número grande (pois ele estará no final)
    let pos = ordemIndices.hasOwnProperty(type) ? parseInt(ordemIndices[type]) : Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    // se tem extra, o valor é maior porque vai depois
    return [parseInt(number), pos, extra ? 1 : 0];
}

const ordemIndices = {};
for (var i = 0; i < orderBy.length; i++) {
    ordemIndices[orderBy[i]] = i;
}

const criterioTipoNumero = /^(extra-)?([-a-z]+)(\d*)/i;
arrayFood.sort(function(a, b) {
    var [numA, indexA, extraA] = getSortInfo(a.food, ordemIndices, criterioTipoNumero);
    var [numB, indexB, extraB] = getSortInfo(b.food, ordemIndices, criterioTipoNumero);
    // primeiro verifica a posição do tipo no array orderBy
    let cmp = indexA - indexB;
    // se a posição é igual, o desempate é primeiro pelo "extra", e depois pelo número
    if (cmp === 0) {
        // desempara pelo "extra"
        cmp = extraA - extraB;
        if (cmp === 0) { // se extra é igual, desempata pelo número
            cmp = numA - numB;
        }
    }
    return cmp;
});

console.log(arrayFood);
```

Comment: Os valores que tem o extra sempre terão o valor "salad" (por exemplo) no nome, então por padrão sempre vai ter um dos nomes listados no array. Ou seja, por isso uso o include pra isso, porq ele pode ter o extra na frente e um numeral no final, mas o padrão é sempre ter de toda forma o que vem no array orderBy no valor.

Comment: @DanielaGross Mas se tem "salad2" e "extra-salad2", como deve ficar a ordem entre eles? E vi que vc mudou a resposta aceita (o checkmark verde), note que vc só pode marcar uma resposta (a que melhor resolveu o problema). Ao mudar para a outra, vc desmarcou esta (não sei se foi intencional, mas enfim, é só para deixar claro que só pode uma, então vc tem que escolher uma delas - mesmo que ambas resolvam, tem que escolher a que vc acha que melhor resolveu)

Comment: @DanielaGross E a outra resposta não inclui os "extra-" no resultado final, era isso mesmo? Repare que eu dou as 2 opções (com e sem os extras), mas seria melhor se vc confirmasse o que é para fazer com os extras

Comment: Eu não vi que tinha desmarcado, queria marcar as duas por ambas foram dedicadas e boas ideias, mas marcarei a sua pois tem a inclusão dos extras mesmo. Respondendo a pergunta do comportamento do extra-salad2 entre o salad2 deve ficar assim: salad1, salad2, extrasalad1, extrasalad2...

Comment: @DanielaGross Se vc achou que ambas as respostas foram úteis, [vc pode dar um voto positivo](/help/privileges/vote-up) nelas (isso sim, vc pode votar em quantas respostas quiser)

Comment: @DanielaGross De qualquer forma, adicionei uma opção para ordenas os extras também

Answer (score 2):

Para ordenar de forma tão arbitrária, conforme o orderBy informado, pode transformar o seu [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) de objetos em um único [objeto literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), onde o valor que você quer ordenar passa a ser um atributo deste objeto literal, contendo o valor de cada objeto do array inicial.

Depois pode fazer um [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) na sua lista de ordenação e verificar se o valor que deseja está no novo objeto literal, caso esteja, adiciona em um novo array que conterá os dados ordenados.

Observações mais específicas: Foi necessário criar mais um array de índices extras, pois neste caso específico de ordenação, existem elementos do array de ordenação complementados com números. Nem todos os elementos possuem um correspondente no orderBy informado.

```js
const arrayFood = [
  {food: 'dessert', name: 'sagu de tangerina'},
  {food: 'garnish2', name: 'moranga refogada com bacon'},
  {food: 'salad2', name: 'pimentão colorido'},
  {food: 'rice', name: 'arroz'},
  {food: 'brownRice', name: 'arroz integral'},
  {food: 'salad4', name: 'beterraba ralada'},
  {food: 'salad3', name: 'agrião com manga'},
  {food: 'meat2', name: 'filezinho de frango empanado'},
  {food: 'cutFruit', name: 'melancia'},
  {food: 'meat1', name: 'dobradinha'},
  {food: 'salad1', name: 'escarola frisse'},
  {food: 'bean', name: 'feijão'},
  {food: 'garnish1', name: 'batata rustica II'},
  {food: 'salad5', name: 'chucrute caseiro'},
  {food: 'meat3', name: 'ovo assado'},
  {food: 'extra-garnish2', name: 'Bacon para G2'},
  {food: 'extra-dessert1', name: 'Pudim prestigio'},
  {food: 'extra-salad2', name: 'Acelga'},
  {food: 'extra-meat2', name: 'Filezinho fgo empanado ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-garnish3', name: 'Macarrão  a Siliciana ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-meat1', name: 'Escalope ao molho sugo ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-salad1', name: 'Radite'},
];

let orderBy = ["salad", "cutFruit", "dessert", "syrup", "coldSauce", "hotSauce", "garnish", "rice", "bean", "meat"];

const objetoFood = {};
const arrayFoodOrdenado = [];
const extraIndices = ['', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arrayFood.forEach(function(obj) {
    objetoFood[obj.food] = obj;
});

orderBy.forEach(function(ordem) {
    extraIndices.forEach(function(indice) {
        if (objetoFood[(ordem + indice)]) {
            arrayFoodOrdenado.push(objetoFood[(ordem + indice)]);
        }
    });
});

console.log(arrayFoodOrdenado);
```

Solução específica para o comentário: "Muito obrigada pela resposta. Porém o único problema da sua solução, é que na minha situação os **índices que tem os números(1, 2, 3, 4), podem ser infinitos**. Então não consigo estar aplicando. Mas muito obrigada pela ideia!".

Os dois primeiros parágrafos e a primeira solução, atendem mais o objetivo do site e ajudam quem tiver o problema: **"Como ordeno um objeto com base na ordem de um array?"**.

Essa parte abaixo é mais específica para o problema da autora da pergunta, conforme comentário destacado.

```js
const arrayFood = [
  {food: 'dessert', name: 'sagu de tangerina'},
  {food: 'garnish2', name: 'moranga refogada com bacon'},
  {food: 'salad2', name: 'pimentão colorido'},
  {food: 'rice', name: 'arroz'},
  {food: 'brownRice', name: 'arroz integral'},
  {food: 'salad4', name: 'beterraba ralada'},
  {food: 'salad3', name: 'agrião com manga'},
  {food: 'meat2', name: 'filezinho de frango empanado'},
  {food: 'cutFruit', name: 'melancia'},
  {food: 'meat1', name: 'dobradinha'},
  {food: 'salad1', name: 'escarola frisse'},
  {food: 'bean', name: 'feijão'},
  {food: 'garnish1', name: 'batata rustica II'},
  {food: 'salad5', name: 'chucrute caseiro'},
  {food: 'meat3', name: 'ovo assado'},
  {food: 'extra-garnish2', name: 'Bacon para G2'},
  {food: 'extra-dessert1', name: 'Pudim prestigio'},
  {food: 'extra-salad2', name: 'Acelga'},
  {food: 'extra-meat2', name: 'Filezinho fgo empanado ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-garnish3', name: 'Macarrão  a Siliciana ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-meat1', name: 'Escalope ao molho sugo ( reg.)'},
  {food: 'extra-salad1', name: 'Radite'},
];

let orderBy = ["salad", "cutFruit", "dessert", "syrup", "coldSauce", "hotSauce", "garnish", "rice", "bean", "meat"];

const objetoFood = {};
const arrayFoodOrdenado = [];

arrayFood.forEach(function(obj) {
    // remove os números do atributo food
    let atributo = obj.food.replace(/\d/g, '');
    if (!objetoFood[atributo]) {
        // cria um array
        objetoFood[atributo] = [];
    }
    // gera uma lista de objetos para o atributo
    objetoFood[atributo].push(obj);
});

orderBy.forEach(function(ordem) {
    if (objetoFood[ordem]) {
        // ordena pelos números do atributo food
        let arrayTemp = objetoFood[ordem].sort(function(objA, objB) {
            return (objA.food.replace(/\D/g, '') - objB.food.replace(/\D/g, ''));
        })
        
        arrayTemp.forEach(function(obj) {
            arrayFoodOrdenado.push(obj);
        });        
    }
});

console.log(arrayFoodOrdenado);
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela resposta. Porém o único problema da sua solução, é que na minha situação os índices que tem os números(1, 2, 3, 4), podem ser infinitos. Então não consigo estar aplicando. Mas muito obrigada pela ideia!

Comment: Se você tem acesso a geração desses dados, seria melhor organizar de forma mais adequada, como por exemplo {food: 'meat', names: ['dobradinha' , 'ovo assado']} ao invés de meat1, meat2, ..., meatN.

Comment: Eu tenho esse acesso, mas esse meat1, meat2, meat3, são necessários pois são usados como ID em outros lugares.

Comment: Pode ser então: {food: 'meat', lista: [{name: 'dobradinha', id: 1} , {name: 'ovo assado', id: 2}]}, que tal?